# Given a list, how can I perform some transformation only on sub-lists whose each two elements satisfy a binary predicate?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, list-processing

(In my actual use case I have a list of type `[SomeType]`, `SomeType` having a finite number of constructors, all nullary; in the following I'll use `String` instead of `[SomeType]` and use only 4 `Char`s, to simplify a bit.)

I have a list like this `"aaassddddfaaaffddsssadddssdffsdf"` where each element can be one of `'a'`, `'s'`, `'d'`, `'f'`, and I want to do some further processing on each contiguous sequence of non-`a`s, let's say turning them upper case and reversing the sequence, thus obtaining `"aaaFDDDDSSaaaSSSDDFFaFDSFFDSSDDD"`. (**I've added the reversing requirement to make it clear that the processing involves *all* the contiguous non `'a'`-s at the same time.**)

To turn each sub-`String` upper case, I can use this:

```hs
func :: String -> String
func = reverse . map Data.Char.toUpper
```

But how do I run that `func` only on the sub-`String`s of non-`'a'`s?

My first thought is that `Data.List.groupBy` can be useful, and the overall solution could be:

```hs
concat $ map (\x -> if head x == 'a' then x else func x)
       $ Data.List.groupBy ((==) `on` (== 'a')) "aaassddddfaaaffddsssadddssdffsdf"
```

This solution, however, does not convince me, as I'm using `== 'a'` both when grouping (which to me seems good and unavoidable) and when deciding whether I should turn a group upper case.

I'm looking for advices on how I can accomplish this small task in the best way.

Comment: What should happen if the processing of the non-`a`s shortens the list?

Comment: @danidiaz, nothing special, the final result would be a shorter list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could classify the list elements by the predicate *before* grouping. Note that I’ve reversed the sense of the predicate to indicate which elements are subject to the transformation, rather than which elements are preserved.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Control.Arrow ((&&&))
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.Monoid (First(..))

mapSegmentsWhere
  :: forall a. (a -> Bool) -> ([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]
mapSegmentsWhere p f
  = concatMap (applyMatching . sequenceA)  -- [a]
  . groupBy ((==) `on` fst)                -- [[(First Bool, a)]]
  . map (First . Just . p &&& id)          -- [(First Bool, a)]
  where
    applyMatching :: (First Bool, [a]) -> [a]
    applyMatching (First (Just matching), xs)
      = applyIf matching f xs

    applyIf :: forall a. Bool -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
    applyIf condition f
      | condition = f
      | otherwise = id
```

Example use:

```
> mapSegmentsWhere (/= 'a') (reverse . map toUpper) "aaassddddfaaaffddsssadddssdffsdf"
"aaaFDDDDSSaaaSSSDDFFaFDSFFDSSDDD"
```

Here I use the `First` monoid with `sequenceA` to merge the lists of adjacent matching elements from `[(Bool, a)]` to `(Bool, [a])`, but you could just as well use something like `map (fst . head &&& map snd)`. You can also skip the `ScopedTypeVariables` if you don’t want to write the type signatures; I just included them for clarity.

Comment: For my own record, playing a bit, I've verified that `&&&`, in this specific case, is equivalent to `(,) <$> (First . Just . p) <*> id`; and given its description ([_send the input to both argument arrows and combine their output_](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#v:-38--38--38-)), it seems exactly that; to rephrase it, my understanding is that `f &&& g` is equal to `(,) <$> f <*> g`.

Comment: So, in a way, you use `p` once for each character, but you don't throw away that result (as I do in my attempt instead), but you store it using the trick of the pair; then you still rely on the first `Bool` of each group, but you do it via the `First` monoid. However this makes you use a `Maybe` where it's not really needed, no? However, I still need some time to through the `concatMap (applyMatching . sequenceA)` part.

Comment: @Enrico: Yeah, `&&&` (which I pronounce “and” or “both…and…of…”) in the `->` arrow is just a more concise way of doing `liftA2 (,) f g`. The `Maybe` is unfortunate, I agree, but the problem is that you can’t use `Data.Semigroup.First` (which doesn’t have a `Maybe`, and consequently only has a `Semigroup` instance, no `Monoid`) because `sequenceA` to go from `[(a, b)]` to `(a, [b])` requires `Monoid a`. There’s probably a way around it that I’m not seeing. It would help if `groupBy` returned `[NonEmpty a]` and there were more `Semigroup`-only tools, but that ecosystem isn’t fleshed out yet.

Comment: I like it, and I've understood most of it (well, writing this code myself out of nothing is another story). I only have a doubt about how `sequenceA` works in this case. I mean, I see the result and see it's reasonable, but I don't understand how it happens. I've asked the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64177058/how-does-sequencea-work-on-lists-of-pairs).

Answer (score 1):

If we need to remember the difference between the `'a'`s and the rest, let's put them in different branches of an `Either`. In fact, let's define a newtype now that we are at it:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

import Data.Bifoldable
import Data.Char
import Data.List

newtype Bunched a b = Bunched [Either a b] deriving (Functor, Foldable)

instance Bifunctor Bunched where
  bimap f g (Bunched b) = Bunched (fmap (bimap f g) b)

instance Bifoldable Bunched where
  bifoldMap f g (Bunched b) = mconcat (fmap (bifoldMap f g) b)
```

`fmap` will let us work over the non-separators. [`fold`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:fold) will return the concatenation of the non-separators, [`bifold`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Bifoldable.html#v:bifold) will return the concatenation of everything. Of course, we could have defined separate functions unrelated to `Foldable` and `Bifoldable`, but why avoid already existing abstractions?

To split the list, we can use an [`unfoldr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:unfoldr) that alternately searches for `a`s and non-`a`s with the [`span`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/GHC-List.html#v:span) function:

```
splitty :: Char -> String -> Bunched String String
splitty c str = Bunched $ unfoldr step (True, str)
  where
    step (_, []) = Nothing
    step (True, span (== c) -> (as, ys)) = Just (Left as, (False, ys))
    step (False, span (/= c) -> (xs, ys)) = Just (Right xs, (True, ys))
```

Putting it to work:

```
ghci> bifold . fmap func . splitty 'a' $ "aaassddddfaaaffddsssadddssdffsdf"
"aaaFDDDDSSaaaSSSDDFFaFDSFFDSSDDD"
```

---

**Note**: `Bunched` is actually the same as `Tannen [] Either` from the [bifunctors](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-5.5.7/docs/Data-Bifunctor-Tannen.html) package, if you don't mind the extra dependency.

Answer (score 1):

There are other answers here, but I think they get too excited about iteration abstractions. A manual recursion, alternately taking things that match the predicate and things that don't, makes this problem exquisitely simple:

```
onRuns :: Monoid m => (a -> Bool) -> ([a] -> m) -> ([a] -> m) -> [a] -> m
onRuns p = go p (not . p) where
    go _ _ _ _ [] = mempty
    go p p' f f' xs = case span p xs of
        (ts, rest) -> f ts `mappend` go p' p f' f rest
```

Try it out in ghci:

```
Data.Char> onRuns ('a'==) id (reverse . map toUpper) "aaassddddfaaaffddsssadddssdffsdf"
"aaaFDDDDSSaaaSSSDDFFaFDSFFDSSDDD"
```

Comment: I find list comprehensions clearer and much more visually apparent. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution - function `process` below - that only requires that you define two functions `isSpecial` and `func`. Given a constructor from your type `SomeType`, `isSpecial` determines whether it is one of those constructors that form a special sublist or not. The function `func` is the one you included in your question; it defines what should happen with the special sublists.

The code below is for character lists. Just change `isSpecial` and `func` to make it work for your lists of constructors.

```
isSpecial c = c /= 'a'
func = reverse . map toUpper

turn = map (\x -> ([x], isSpecial x)) 

amalgamate []  = []
amalgamate [x] = [x]
amalgamate ((xs, xflag) : (ys, yflag) : rest)
   | xflag /= yflag = (xs, xflag) : amalgamate ((ys, yflag) : rest)
   | otherwise      = amalgamate ((xs++ys, xflag) : rest)

work = map (\(xs, flag) -> if flag then func xs else xs)

process = concat . work . amalgamate . turn
```

Let's try it on your example:

```
*Main> process "aaassddddfaaaffddsssadddssdffsdf"
"aaaFDDDDSSaaaSSSDDFFaFDSFFDSSDDD"
*Main>
```

Applying one function at a time, shows the intermediate steps taken:

```
*Main> turn "aaassddddfaaaffddsssadddssdffsdf"
[("a",False),("a",False),("a",False),("s",True),("s",True),("d",True),
("d",True),("d",True),("d",True),("f",True),("a",False),("a",False),
("a",False),("f",True),("f",True),("d",True),("d",True),("s",True),
("s",True),("s",True),("a",False),("d",True),("d",True),("d",True),
("s",True),("s",True),("d",True),("f",True),("f",True),("s",True),
("d",True),("f",True)]
*Main> amalgamate it
[("aaa",False),("ssddddf",True),("aaa",False),("ffddsss",True),
("a",False),("dddssdffsdf",True)]
*Main> work it
["aaa","FDDDDSS","aaa","SSSDDFF","a","FDSFFDSSDDD"]
*Main> concat it
"aaaFDDDDSSaaaSSSDDFFaFDSFFDSSDDD"
*Main>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can just do what you describe, step by step, getting a clear simple minimal code which we can easily read and understand later on:

```
foo :: (a -> Bool) -> ([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]
foo p f xs = [ a
         | g <- groupBy ((==) `on` fst) 
                      [(p x, x) | x <- xs]  -- [ (True, 'a'), ... ]
         , let (t:_, as) = unzip g          -- ( [True, ...], "aaa" )
         , a <- if t then as else (f as) ]  -- final concat

         -- unzip :: [(b, a)] -> ([b], [a])
```

We break the list into same-`p` spans and unpack each group with the help of `unzip`. Trying it out:

```
> foo (=='a') reverse "aaabcdeaa"
"aaaedcbaa"
```

So no, using `== 'a'` *is* avoidable and hence not especially good, introducing an unnecessary constraint on your data type when all we need is equality on Booleans.

Comment: You can match the originally-requested type a bit closer by adding an additional clause, as in `[ a | ... , a <- if t then as else f as ]`. ...and if you want to go all in on list comprehensions, how about `[(p x, x) | x <- xs]` for the `zip`+`map` bit?

Comment: ah yes I missed the final concat, aren't I. and the bit about zip+map is also good, thanks. see, LCs *are* nice and easy to work with. :)