# How does sequenceA work on lists of pairs?

Tags: haskell, applicative

Spin off of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64068980/5825294) question. Intuitively I have understood what `sequenceA` does in that usecase, but not ***how/why*** it works like that.

So it all boils down to this question: how does `sequenceA` work in the following case?

```hs
> sequenceA [("a",1),("b",2),("c",3)]
("abc",[1,2,3])
```

I see that

```hs
sequenceA :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => t (f a) -> f (t a)
```

so in the usecase above the `Traversable` is `[]`, and the `Applicative`, since `(,)` is a binary type constructor, is `(,) a`, which means that the pair is taken as an applicative functor on its `snd` field. And this goes together the list ending up in the `snd` of the result. So we go from a list of pairs to a pair with a list in its second field.

But where does the `"abc"` come from? I mean, I know that it's the concatenation of the `fst` of all the pairs, but I don't know if it's via `++` or via `concat` of the list of the `fst`s. There seems to be nothing in `sequenceA`'s signature to enforce that the `fst`s of the pairs can be combined together.

Still that assumption has to be used somewhere. Indeed, the following fails

```hs
sequenceA [('a',1),('b',2),('c',3)]
```

Comment: Daniel Wagner’s answer already spells it out, but the error message in your failure case also provides a clue: `Could not deduce (Monoid Char) arising from a use of ‘sequenceA’`. It’s trying to combine the first elements of the pairs using `Monoid`, or rather its superclass `Semigroup`’s “append” operation `(<>)`, which for lists is equal to `(++)`. The `(,) a` applicative is the unwrapped version of `Writer a`.

Comment: Incidentally, you can also apply `sequenceA` to `("abc",[1,2,3])`. There the `Traversable` is `((,) String)` and the `Applicative` is `[]`. The result is `[("abc",1),("abc",2),("abc",3)]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Haskell, typeclass instances for a type can be "conditional" on the existence of other typeclass instances for parts of the type. Not *all* type constructors
of the form `((,) a)`are instances of `Applicative`, but *only* those for which the `a` type has a `Monoid` instance.

These required constraints appear before the `=>` in the instance's Haddocks, like this:

```
Monoid a => Applicative ((,) a)
```

Why is the `Monoid` instance required? For one, `pure` for `((,) a)` needs to materialize an `a` value out of thin air to put in the first element of the tuple. `mempty` for the type `a` does the job.

---

There can be chains of required constraints that are several levels deep. For example, why does the following work?

```
ghci> import Datta.Function ((&)) -- flipped application
ghci> [(id :: String -> String, 2 :: Int), (\x -> x ++ x, 1)] & sequenceA & fst $ "foo"
"foofoofoo"
```

Here the first component is a function. As before, it must have a `Monoid` instance for the `sequenceA` to work. But when is the type `a -> b` a `Monoid`? Looking at the Haddocks, we find:

```
Monoid b => Monoid (a -> b)
```

That is, functions are `Monoid`s when the return type (here `String`) is a `Monoid`.

Actually, there's *another* `Monoid` instance for functions available through the [`Endo`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Endo) newtype. It's common to use newtypes to select which instance to use for a given operation, although it requires some amount of wrapping and unwrapping.

Answer (score 7):

It uses `mappend`. The `Applicative` instance it uses looks like this:

```
instance Monoid a => Applicative ((,) a) where
    pure x = (mempty, x)
    (af, f) <*> (ax, x) = (mappend af ax, f x)
```